# No significant performance improvement in multi threading

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I am trying to find a distribution of variables in a NxN matrix. The matrix is filled randomly by numbers from 1 to 10.

I am creating some number of threads (from cmdline input) and assigning each of them some rows(equally distributed to threads) for finding the distribution. But I don't see any performance improvement from single threaded application. Is it a expected result or am I doing something wrong here.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "timing.h"


struct threadInput{
int** inputArray;
int* distribution;
int size;
};

int sizeofArray;
int matrixDistribution[10] = {0};
pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;

void* findDistribution(void* distribution);

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    if(argc < 3){
        printf("%s \n","please enter the size of NxN matrix and number of threads. ex: ./part3parallel.out ");
        exit(0);
    }

    timing_start();
    int numThreads;
    sizeofArray= atoi(argv[1]);
    numThreads = atoi(argv[2]);

    /*generate matrix */
    int array[sizeofArray][sizeofArray];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0;i<sizeofArray;i++){
        for(j=0;j<sizeofArray;j++){
            array[i][j] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
         }
     }

    /* split the array between threads */
    int divideArraybythreads[numThreads];
    memset(divideArraybythreads, 0, sizeof divideArraybythreads);
    int threadCounter = 0;

    for(i=0;i<sizeofArray ;i++){
        divideArraybythreads[threadCounter] = divideArraybythreads[threadCounter] + 1;
        ++threadCounter;
        if(threadCounter > numThreads - 1)
            threadCounter = 0;
    }
    /*****************************/

    struct threadInput ti[numThreads];
    pthread_t threadIds[numThreads];
    int arrayCounter = 0;

    for(i=0;i<numThreads;i++){
       if(divideArraybythreads[i] == 0)
            continue;

        ti[i].inputArray = (int **)malloc(divideArraybythreads[i] * sizeof(int *));
        int j;
        for (j=0; j<divideArraybythreads[i] ; j++){
            ti[i].inputArray[j] = (int *)malloc(sizeofArray * sizeof(int));
            ti[i].inputArray[j] = *(array + arrayCounter);
            arrayCounter++;
        }
        ti[i].size = divideArraybythreads[i];
        ti[i].distribution = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_create(&threadIds[i],&attr, findDistribution,&ti[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<numThreads;i++){
        if(divideArraybythreads[i] == 0)
            continue;
        pthread_join(threadIds[i],NULL);
    }

    for(i=0;i<numThreads;i++){
        if(divideArraybythreads[i] == 0)
            continue;
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            matrixDistribution[j]  =  matrixDistribution[j]  + ti[i].distribution[j];
        }   
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d \n",matrixDistribution[i]);
    }

    timing_stop();

    printf("%lli \n",get_timing());

    return 0;
}


void* findDistribution(void* distribution){
    struct threadInput *arr = (struct threadInput*) distribution;

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<arr->size;i++){
        for(j=0;j<sizeofArray;j++){
            arr->distribution[arr->inputArray[i][j] - 1]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many threads are you creating? And don't include printout in the timing (it can be relatively slow and skew benchmark results).

Comment: I doing a academic project here, where we study the performance when the number of threads is from 2 to 64. And regarding the printout I removed it.Thanks.

Comment: Unclear - what parameters are you passing for your testing?

Comment: 'where we study the performance when the number of threads is from 2 to 64' well, since threads are not always, (it should be 'hardly ever'), used in this 'continually create, join, terminate' manner, you should be careful when drawing conclusions from such studies.

Comment: we pass size of matrix and number of threads for solving the distribution of random numbers in matrix.  But I find that the problem is with resource creation here.

Comment: 'we pass size of matrix' sure, but what actual values are you testing with?

Comment: The matrix is filled with random values.

Comment: @Som Command-line values!  How big is your matrix that you test with?

Comment: @MartinJames between 64 and 1000.

Comment: 64*64 is much too small.  1000*1000 is getting there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of creating a thread takes up a lot of resources. So if you create threads just to do some trivial calculations, you might end up with worse performance than a single threaded application. Multi-threading only pays off performance-wise where there are a whole lot of processing work to be done, and where there is a case to "parallelize" the program, such as "go through this huge array and perform lots of calculations per item".

Note that the reason why you'd make a program multi-threaded is not often related to performance at all. The most common reason is that you wish to execute several things at once, such as having one thread handling the GUI and another thread doing calculations without freezing the GUI.